# How to correctly load Flask app module in uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

[EDIT]

I managed to load the flask app module by starting uwsgi from within the project folder. I now have a problem with nginx not having permission to the socket file though (scroll down to the end of the question). If anybody can help with that..?

[/EDIT]

Following [this tutorial](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) I'm trying to run my Flask website with [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [nginx](http://nginx.org/). When doing exactly as the tutorial says it works fine. I now want to run my own website though. And the structure of my own website project looks as follows:

```
myownproject
   |-app
       | -__init__.py
   |-run.py
   |-myownproject_nginx.conf
   |-myownproject_uwsgi.ini
```

in which `app` is loaded in `__init__.py` like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and myownproject_uwsgi.ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /home/kramer65/myownproject

#python module to import
app = app
module = %(app)

# I disabled these lines below because I don't use a venv (please don't ask)
# home = %(base)/venv
# pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/kramer65/myownproject/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds the flask application inside the imported module
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

But when I run this:

```
$ uwsgi --ini /home/kramer65/myownproject/myownproject_uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/kramer65/myownproject/myownproject_uwsgi.ini
```

I get the following logs in `/var/log/uwsgi/myownproject_uwsgi.log`:

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ImportError: No module named app
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

Why doesn't uwsgi find my callable? And why is the `mountpoint` empty (`=''`)? What am I doing wrong here?

Does anybody know how I can get this to work properly?

[EDIT]

Okay, I tried running `uwsgi --ini /home/kramer65/myownproject/myownproject_uwsgi.ini` from within the `myownproject` project folder, which solves this problem; it now finds the callable and that seems to work fine.

I still get a 502 though, the next problem seems to be a permission problem with nginx not having permission to the socket file. `/var/log/nginx/error.log` says:

> 2015/10/27 11:40:36 [crit] 14276#0: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/home/kramer65/myownproject/myownproject_uwsgi.sock failed (13:
>   Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   80.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:/home/kramer65/myownproject/myownproject_uwsgi.sock:",
>   host: "52.xx.xx.xxx"

So I changed the `chmod-socket = 666` to `chmod-socket = 777`. When doing an `ls -l` I actually see the socket file having full permissions, but I still get the error I pasted above.

Any ideas to get this working?

Comment: I don't know about uwsgi because I often use PRoxy pass, but I wouldn't disable the home and Python path lines. Have you tried using your default Python location instead. 'which python' on the cl might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base` config is just a internal variable. The part you commented out caused your problem.

If you don't want to use virtualenv and set your pythonpath, change the `base` config to `chdir`.

`chdir = /home/kramer65/myownproject`

Internally, uWSGI will run from `chdir` instead of from the current directory.

About the socket permission problem, the nginx user (probably `www-data`) does not have access to your personal folder (`/home/kramer65/`). You must set the socket to another folder, where nginx and uwsgi have access.

Comment: Alright, that indeed enables to me to run the `uwsgi`-command from any location. Thanks! But it doesn't solve the other error, being that nginx has a `Permission denied` error on the `myownproject_uwsgi.sock` (see [EDIT] in question), event though the socket file is `chmod`ed to 777 and owned by the `kramer65` user. Any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: I don't know your nginx conf, but nginx probably can't acces the folder, even if it can access the file.

Comment: Awesome! That was it!! You dear sir, have just made my day even more sunnier than it already was!

Comment: Good to know. This permission denied error is probably the most common issue during the first deploy. After you understand the problem, it is easy to fix, but nginx does not give you a good error message.